# Защита сайта при загрузки фото и видео

Tags: php, безопасность, взлом, уязвимости

Есть сайт (на php) на котором я хочу реализовать загрузку/показ фото и видео. К каким мерам безопасности я должен придерживаться и что для этого я должен делать (Меня интерисует конкретно безопасность то есть защита от хакерских атак)

Comment: Посмотрите здесь например: https://habr.com/post/44610/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос обширный. Векторов атак может быть несколько и все их рассматривать можно долго.

Но пожалуй основное, на что стоит обратить внимание - чтобы вам вместо картинки не передали на сервер что-то другое: php скрипт, html страницу, или другой контент, который при публикации на сервере потенциально может вызвать проблему: php срипт думаю комментировать не требуется; а вот html-страница может содержать например js код для кражи cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Затрону тему немного более обширную - лучше взять за правило проверку всех вводимых полей с целью избежать нежелательных инъекций и проникновений на сайт.Вот пример регулярок, которые помогут вам в данных проверках:

```
Набор из букв и цифр (латиница):
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
Набор из букв и цифр (латиница + кириллица):
^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9]+$
Домен (например abcd.com):
^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
IPv4:
((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)
IPv6:
((^|:)([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4})){1,8}$
Имя пользователя (с ограничением 2-20 символов, которыми могут быть буквы и цифры, первый символ обязательно буква):
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$
Пароль (Строчные и прописные латинские буквы, цифры):
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$
Пароль (Строчные и прописные латинские буквы, цифры, спецсимволы. Минимум 8 символов):
(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
Дата в формате YYYY-MM-DD:
[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]) 
UPD. Более строгая проверка, предложенная runcore:
(19|20)\d\d-((0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d)|(0[13-9]|1[012])-30|(0[13578]|1[02])-31)
Дата в формате DD/MM/YYYY:
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d
Целые числа и числа с плавающей точкой (разделитель точка):
\-?\d+(\.\d{0,})?
UUID:
^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}\-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$
Широта или долгота:
-?\d{1,3}\.\d+

UPD. E-mail (от kvf77):
^[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}$
```

Comment: Лучше организовать архитектуру сайта так, чтобы подобные проверки были в принципе не нужны, особенно в откровенно неуместных местах вроде пароля, почты, домена и полей с произвольным текстом вроде этого комментария

Comment: о какой информационной безопасности вы пишите, если есть грубые ошибки в коде regexp?) например, "^[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}$" - не экранируется точка в первых кавычках (то есть в это поле вообще можно вбить все, что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Обязательно проверять содержимое файла по mime типу. В php есть встроенная функция [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mime-content-type.php) или сторонние [наработки](https://github.com/ralouphie/mimey).
Это конечно не единственное что поможет избежать действий лиц с пониженной социальной ответственностью :)

Comment: Ну и загрузят с типом image/png файл avatarka.png.php.png с RCE внутри, и толку?) Вообще, имя файла совсем не обязательно указывает на содержимое файла, и mime_content_type вполне может и соврать

Comment: С этой точки зрения соврать может все, полагаться на имя файла и расширение точно не стоит, а вот содержимое анализировать необходимо. Это первый шаг. Второй шаг, например если речь идёт о изображении, попробовать изменить ему размеры, ImageMagic например, если он выдаст ошибку, то файл в топку, сендера в бан :) Вариантов проверок множество, каждый выбирает оптимальный для себя.

Comment: Полностью согласен, но ваш ответ всё-таки не про содержимое, а про имя) Как минимум вторая ссылка

Comment: А вот ImageMagic дело хорошее, его бы и стоило в ответе упомянуть)

Comment: 'Обязательно проверять содержимое файла по mime типу' - или у вас по другому опубликовано?

Comment: Содержимое надо проверять по содержимому, а не по каким-то косвенным путям. Справится ли mime_content_type с rarjpeg'ом, например?

Comment: С phpjpeg'ом не справился :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/3isZu.png